# Make new variable in script calling from php

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm using jquery-3.3.1.min to live update and calling it to my main.php

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
            setInterval(function () {
            $('#show').load('smoke.php')
            $('#show2').load('pids.php')
            $('#show3').load('flame.php')
            $('#show4').load('panic.php')

                }, 2000);
            });
```

/////
I'm echo in php using

```
                $smoke_status            = $row['smoke_status'];
                $pids_status             = $row['pids_status'];
                $flame_status            = $row['flame_status'];
                $panic_status            = $row['panic_status'];
                $startdate               = $row['startdate'];
                $stopdate                = $row['stopdate'];

                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td id='show'></td>";
                echo "<td id='show2'></td>";
                echo "<td id='show3'></td>";
                echo "<td id='show4'></td>";
                echo "<td>$startdate</td>";
                echo "<td>$stopdate</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
```

but now...i want to make my live update data into a variable in script
how can i declare it.
i'm success calling this

```
          var i = <?php echo $panic_status  ?>;
```

and how can i call

```
             echo "<td id='show'></td>";
                echo "<td id='show2'></td>";
                echo "<td id='show3'></td>";
                echo "<td id='show4'></td>";
```

into new variable??plsss help and srry for the long question

Answer (score 0):

Hello I do not know what you are actually doing with the code. its so scattered that one cannot easily know where to start

1.) You are displaying a result and i did not see where you are trying to escape those database with **htmlentities()** or **htmlspecialchars()** functions against xss attack.

2.) I do not know whether you are still using **mysql_connect** deprecated functions in your database query. if so please better move it to **mysqli** or **PDO**.

3.) i can see you calling simultaneously four php files simultaneously with 2 seconds call. What is it you are trying to achieve. This will cause alot  of issues to the server including  latency, poor performance and over consumption 
of data. If you need a real time update why don't you switch over to nodejs and socket.io.

To answer your question, I have created an ajax example to get you started

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>

         $(document).ready(function(){


         //$('#result').click(function(){

         var post1 = 'data to post if any';





        $('#loader').fadeIn(400).html('Please Wait. Data is being Loaded');


         // assuming that you want query result by posting a variable
         var datasend = "alert1="+ post1;

         $.ajax({

         type:'POST',
         url:'smoke.php',
         data:datasend,
         crossDomain: true,
         cache:false,
         success:function(msg){

         $('#loader').hide();
         $('#result').fadeIn('slow').prepend(msg);
         }

         });

         //})

         });


    </script>


<div id="loader"></div>
<div id="result"></div>
```

The above script will make a call to smoke.php and display any result contained there in

```
<?php

$smoke_status = 'I am not smoking';

/* if data is to be displayed in html form,  you have to escape it with either htmlspecialchars() or htmlentities() functions to ensure
that XXS attack is not possible. you can read further on how to escape both single, double quotes with it as case may be
*/
echo htmlspecialchars($smoke_status);
?>
```

Comment: im using this to fetch from databased and i know it not proper live updated<?php 
$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'prison');
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection error: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
$result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM incident ORDER BY incident_ID DESC LIMIT 1");
if ($result->num_rows > 0){
  while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo $row['smoke_status'] . '<br>';
  }
}
flush();
    sleep(1);
?>

Comment: So how can i use the data <div id="loader"></div>
<div id="result"></div> or make it as a variable?

Comment: what variable are you talking about. How can you set Ajax result as variable at backend. Ajax/Jquery call is a front end that makes call to the backend.. You are writing your code the wrong way and it seems you did not read what I posted above. You did not escape the displayed result with htmlentities() functions thus your script is vulnerable to XSS Attack

Comment: See am gonna help you once more by trying to rewrite your code once more to help you achieve your goal.

Comment: <?php


/*
create table incident(incident_ID int primary key auto_increment,smoke_status varchar(20));
insert into incident values(1,'iam not a Smoker');
*/

// use PDO
$db = new PDO (
 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=remotedb;charset=utf8', 
 'root', // username

 '' // password
); 


$sql = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM incident ORDER BY incident_ID DESC LIMIT 1');
$sql->execute(array());
$count = $sql->rowCount();
if($count>0){
while ($row = $sql->fetch()) {

echo $s_s=htmlentities($row['smoke_status'], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
}
}
flush(); sleep(1);

?>